# NSPredicate filter inherited object in coredata

Tags: ios, objective-c, inheritance, core-data, nspredicate

**QUESTION**

Hi all, here I have designed my CoreData as like this (I'll write as simple as possible, while my real data is much more complex):

```
Product (Abstract)
   - NSString *productName
   - NSDecimalNumber *productPrice
   - NSString *productType

ProductComplex : Product
   - (NSSet <ProductSimple *> *)childProducts

ProductSimple : Product
   - (ProductComplex *)parentProduct
```

So basically, the `Product` is an abstract type, which has 2 properties: name and price. There are 2 inheritances to Product:

1. `ProductComplex`: This may have many child products.
2. `ProductSimple`: This may be a child of a complex product or not.

Then, I have a list to display all product (the abstract `Product`, of course). Now I want to create a predicate to filter the `Product` list with these conditions:

1. Only display `ProductComplex` which have `childProducts` (`childProducts.@count > 0`).
2. Only display `ProductSimple` which doesn't have any `parentProduct` (`parentProduct = nil`).

**MY TRY**

I'm using `NSFetchResultController`, where the entityName is `Product`. I've tried create a predicate:

```
NSPredicate *predicate = [NSPredicate predicateWithFormat:@"childProducts.@count > 0 OR parentProduct = nil"];
```

This cause crash when perform fetching the fetchResultController:

`if (![self.fetchedResultsController performFetch:&error]) {...}`

This is the simplified crash reason:

> *** Terminating app due to uncaught exception 'NSInvalidArgumentException', reason: 'Can't have a non-relationship
>   collection element in a subquerySUBQUERY(childProducts, $child,
>   $child.productPrice > "0")'

Please help me create a filter for those.

**EDIT 1**

I've even tried this something like this predicate below to make sure it has the relationship, but this doesn't work also.

`[NSPredicate predicateWithFormat:@"productType = 'complex' AND childProducts.@count > 0"]`

**EDIT 2**

After turn on SQL debug mode, I've found the SQL that fetch generated out. Read that SQL query, I think it's impossible to do what I ask for :( Still hope for an answer for that.

Comment: I think the entity name should be either 'ProductComplex' or 'ProductSimple'. Entity 'Product' is an abstract or you can say a parent entity.

Comment: But my list is a mixed with both complex and simple. What's the meaning of abstraction if I query exactly `Complex` or `Simple`?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It is impossible unfortunately. Try to avoid using `inheritance` in your DB. You can have `ProductComplex` and `ProductSimple` as tables with references to the base Product table using foreign key. It allows to avoid inheritance and to improve performance.